# Прозрачный RichEdit

Tags: delphi

У меня такой вопрос к экспертам, можно ли сделать прозрачным компонент RichEdit или
это в принципе невозможно и если это не возможно, то может вы подскажете какой-нибудь компонент аналогичный ему, но со свойством transparent. Может кто-нибудь когда-нибудь
писал подобный компонент и он может поделится опытом.

Comment: ПРозрачным врятли. А вот невидимым вполне реально - Visible поставь false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самое простое, что здесь можно сделать это следующее:

1. Ставим у RichEdit свойство color такого цвета, какого точно не будет текст (или менять во время работы программы);
2. У самой формы ставим TransparentColor - True, а TransparentColorValue выбираем тот цвет, который поставили на Color компонента RichEdit (или же всё это устанавливаем программно на обработчике формы OnCreate).

Достаточно на обработчике формы OnCreate поставить какой-нибудь нестандартный цвет, например, RGB(255,255,254) - для глаза белый, а для компьютера - нет (TransparentColorValue и Color компонента RichEdit), чтобы всё работало, так, как цвет текста обычно выбирается в FontDialog-е из списка стандартных.

P. S. Я недавно на подобный вопрос отвечал здесь же, вопрос: "Вывод текста на canvas в Delphi". Там я выкладывал код, если что, может пригодиться.